# ArrayList with images JAVA

Tags: java, image, url, arraylist

I have array list with images url. Then I am creating images, but only one is showing in scroll panel.

There is my code :

```
try{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.size(); i++) {
        String url2 = arrayName.get(i);
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL(url2)));
        picLabel.setSize(100,100);
        scrollPane.add(picLabel);
        lol.add( scrollPane);
        System.out.println(url2);
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

The JScrollPane has a JComponent as viewport. You should add your components to the viewport view and not to the JScrollPane directly. Hence it consists of JScrollBars, header, the JViewport etc.

The "thing" which is scrolled ist the JComponent set as viewport.

Hence you must set a View containing all your images as viewport of the JScrollPane and it should work. See [JScrollPanel JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
imagePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
scrollPanel = new JscrollPane(imagePanel);
try{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.size(); i++) {
        String url2 = arrayName.get(i);
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL(url2)));
        picLabel.setSize(100,100);
        imagePanel.add(picLabel);
        System.out.println(url2);
    }
lol.add( scrollPane);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```